# Why does va_arg(va_list, type) give me a C6285 warning?

Tags: c++, warnings, variadic

Everything is working as intended, and I get the values I need from va_arg(va_list, type), but I get this warning everywhere I call va_arg:

`Warning    C6285   (<non-zero constant> || <non-zero constant>) is always a non-zero constant.  Did you intend to use the bitwise-and operator?`

Example code:

```
void Logger::log(LogLevel level, const char* location, uint32_t line, const char* format, ...)
{
    va_list arg_ptr;
    va_start(arg_ptr, format);

    while (*format) {
        // ...
        if (*format == 'd') { // 
            int i = va_arg(arg_ptr, int); // <-- Warning is reported here
            // ...
        }
        // ...
        ++format;
    }
    // ...
    va_end(arg_ptr);
}
```

Why do I get this warning and how can I get rid of it?

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2019 with Visual C++ 2019

Comment: You are using C++ and we have year 2020! So please do not use old fashioned `C` variadic arguments, take advantage of template variadic arguments.

Comment: Variadic templates is not an option if one desires that the implementation is hidden in a .cpp file.

Comment: There is no (a || b) in the given example, please show the full function

Comment: @Mestkon There is no (a || b) in my code. That's what gets me.

Comment: It is probably the macro in @rustyx's answer then

Comment: Please point out exactly where warning is reported.

Comment: @MarekR I have edited my question to point out the reported warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`C6###` error codes are IntelliSense codes. These are based on heuristics and are meant to point the attention to potential errors, but can also result in false-positives, which seems to be the case here; it's probably triggering on the `va_arg` implementation in the CRT:

```
#define __crt_va_arg(ap, t)                                               \
    ((sizeof(t) > sizeof(__int64) || (sizeof(t) & (sizeof(t) - 1)) != 0) \  // <== Here
        ? **(t**)((ap += sizeof(__int64)) - sizeof(__int64))             \
        :  *(t* )((ap += sizeof(__int64)) - sizeof(__int64)))
```

I would simply ignore it ...

If it bothers you, report it to the vendor: *Help* → *Send Feedback* → *Report a Problem...*

Comment: Yeah, this is also the conclusion I have come to. Ignoring it is unfortunately not an option, since I have specific requirements for warning-free code. I will take your advice and report it.

Comment: Are you allowed to use a `#pragma` to disable the warning?

Comment: No, `#pragma warning` has no effect on IntelliSense.

Comment: @mdhedelund: intellisense warning is not part of build system normally, so it should not block compilation when treating warnings as errors.